# purchased software

Tags: sql, database, wordpress

I bought usage rights to a confederate soldiers database which is in sql, I bought it to intergrate with my wordpress genealogy blog, and I need to know if there is any way to do this, the place where I purchased will not give my money back, and are not very helpful as far as figuring this out.

thanks,
r. summers

Comment: It sounds like you might benefit from hiring a freelancer to help you out with this.

Answer (score 2):

When you say it's "in sql", what exactly do you mean?

- Do you mean that it's a Microsoft SQL Server database file (.mdf or .sdf file extension)?
- Do you mean that it's a SQL script that generates the database (something like a `CREATE DATABASE` command followed by one or more `CREATE TABLE` commands followed by a bunch of `INSERT` commands)?
- Do you mean something entirely different?